# Accessing environment variable in Newman script

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, newman

I'd like to access variable from my environment and save it to file every time Newman sends a request. I know there is `--export-environment` option while running it from command line, but I need to access it as Postman do through `pm.environment.get("name")` so the final script would look like this

```
newman.run({
    collection: require('./collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli',
    environment: require('./environment.json'),
    exportEnvironment: require('./environment.json'),
    globals: require('./globals.json'),
    exportGlobals: require('./globals.json')
})
.on('request', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    var variable1 = 'first variable' 
    var variable2 = 'second variable'

    fs.appendFile("my_values.txt", variable1 + variable2, function (error) {
        if (error) { 
             console.error(error); 
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use case here?

Comment: @DannyDainton saving part of data to file and process it with bash. I could do this with response data which I currently do, but I need to call another request from tests, which overrides original response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer so I'll post it as there is nothing in documentation about this and couldn't find answer on any of sites. Looks like variables are accessible in `test` event like this

```
newman.run({
    collection: require('./collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli',
    environment: require('./environment.json'),
    exportEnvironment: require('./environment.json'),
    globals: require('./globals.json'),
    exportGlobals: require('./globals.json')
}).on('test', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    var variable1 = data.executions[0].result.environment.values.reference.myVariable1.value;
    var variable2 = data.executions[0].result.environment.values.reference.myVariable2.value + '\n';

    fs.appendFile("output.txt", variable1 + variable2, function (error) {
        if (error) { 
             console.error(error); 
        }
     });
});
```